# Laravel Media Library issue

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Using the Laravel Media Library to add media to the User Model

```
Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (HY000)

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2036 (SQL: select * from media
where media.model_id = 41 and media.model_id is not null 
and media.model_type = App\User)
```

Works fine in my production instance

Having an issue while running it locally

Comment: are you check media is exists?

Comment: Yes Davit .. My db is in aws RDS ..Same I'm using in local .. I doubt some issues with //

Comment: Which is your MySQL version in the local machine?

Comment: MySQL version 8.0.18